# Mockito cannot mock this class exception

Tags: android, mockito

I'm trying to run instrumentation tests in `Release`.
Running the tests on on API 28 - Pie (only) I get the exception below for all tests.
No issues running the same tests on devices with APIs 23-27 & 29

The class is public and not final:

```
    public class AuthManager {...}
```

Changing `debuggable` in `build.gradle` to `true` makes the test run successfully.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Can't exempt class, process is not debuggable

The cause exception above doesn't even show up on search engines.

Relevant configuration:

> androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.27.0"
>   ...
>   androidMinSdkVersion = 23
>   androidTargetSdkVersion = 28
>   androidCompileSdkVersion = 28

Full stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.myapp.data.managers.AuthManager.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.



IMPORTANT INFORMATION FOR ANDROID USERS:

The regular Byte Buddy mock makers cannot generate code on an Android VM!
To resolve this, please use the 'mockito-android' dependency for your application:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22mockito-android%22%20g%3A%22org.mockito%22

Java               : 0.9
JVM vendor name    : The Android Project
JVM vendor version : 2.1.0
JVM name           : Dalvik
JVM version        : 0.9
JVM info           : null
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 4.9.124-g86541ee-ab5292322


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke BaseDexClassLoader#addDexPath(String, boolean)
at SOME_TEST_CASE_CLASS
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at com.myapp.base.CustomTestRunner.onStart(CustomTestRunner.kt:24)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke BaseDexClassLoader#addDexPath(String, boolean)
at net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy$Injecting$Dispatcher$ForAndroidPVm.loadDex(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:540)
at net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy$Injecting.doLoad(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:415)
at net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.load(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:142)
at net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy$Injecting.load(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:408)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:100)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:5662)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:173)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
at org.mockito.android.internal.creation.AndroidByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(AndroidByteBuddyMockMaker.java:39)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1907)
... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't exempt class, process is not debuggable.
at dalvik.system.DexFile.setTrusted(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.setTrusted(DexFile.java:385)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:373)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.addDexPath(DexPathList.java:226)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.addDexPath(BaseDexClassLoader.java:155)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy$Injecting$Dispatcher$ForAndroidPVm.loadDex(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:531)
... 52 more
```

Comment: Is it kotlin and if so, is your class marked as `open`?

Comment: The class is `public` and not `final`

Comment: In Kotlin the class is treated as final unless you declare it as open. I have seen an issue before where I was getting an error because it was not open. Maybe worth a try?

Comment: @StuStirling I'm aware. This is Java though, the class is `public` and not `final`

Comment: You should try to change net.buddy version. I think it is low.